# What does $u_0$ mean in this PDE problem?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Here is the question:

> The function $u(x,t)$ satisfies the partial differential equation
>   $$\frac {\partial u}{\partial t}\ =\ \frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
>   with $(0<x<L, \ \ t>0)$.
>
> The boundary condition are given by:
>   $$u(0,t) = a \qquad u(L,t)=b \qquad u(x,0)=f(x)$$
>   where $a$ and $b$ are constants and $L$ is a positive constant. Solve the following problems.
>
> ($1$) Find the solution $u_0(x)$ of the above equation when $\frac {\partial u}{\partial t} = 0$.
>
> ($2$) Derive the PDE and the boundary conditions for 
>   $$v(x,t) = u(x,t) - u_0(x).$$

Now here goes my confusion:

I can't understand what the u-subscripted zero ($u_0$(x)) means in this case.

My best guess is that $u_0(x)$ is an initial condition at $t = 0$.

But if I try to solve ($1$), I will get
$u(x) = Ax + B$, which contains no $t$. Yeah, I know when $t=0$, the equation won't contain any $t$, but is this correct?

EDITED:

How can I also solve ($2$)?
Why suddenly there is $v(x,t)$?  As far as I know know $u_0(x)$ and $u(x,t)$ now has the same value since $\frac {\partial u}{\partial t} = 0$. Then $v(x,t)$ is zero?

Please help me, somebody. Thank you. :)

Comment: I think $u_0(x)$ is simply the general  solution of $\frac  {\partial^{2}u} {\partial u^{2}}=0$.

Comment: It's just a variable name. $u_0(x)$ is the steady-state solution

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried and updated the follow up question of regarding no 2

Answer (score 3):

If $\frac {\partial u}{\partial t} = 0$, then the function $u$ is independent of the variable $t$, hence $u$ is a function only of $x$:

$$u(x,t)=u_0(x).$$

In this case $\frac {\partial u}{\partial t}\ =\ \frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ means

$$u_0''(x)=0.$$

Thus $u_0$ has the form $u_0(x)=ax+b.$

Comment: Thank fred, does that mean $u_0(x)$ also equal to $f(x)$ in given boundary condition?